# Как сэмулировать event в laravel-echo + pusher-js?

Tags: php, laravel, echo, broadcasting

Привет, надо сэмулировать `event` с помощью `laravel-echo (5.3)`, но нигде не нашел как это сделать. Так как драйвер `pusher`, то видимо можно сделать что-то вроде:

```
Echo.trigger('client-eventName', {data: data}).
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли это?

Спасибо.

PS: Решено.

```
Echo.connector.pusher.channels.trigger(eventName, data);
```